# jqPlot date axis - bars drawn on wrong day?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Pretty simple stuff here:

```
   var dataHits = [['2011-10-16',1],['2011-11-05',7],['2011-11-06',1],['2011-11-09',2],['2011-11-12',5]];
   var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartHits', [dataHits], {
      title:'Zobrazenia profilu spolu',
      seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {            
            barPadding: 0,      // number of pixels between adjacent bars in the same
                                // group (same category or bin).
            barMargin: 0,      // number of pixels between adjacent groups of bars.
            barDirection: 'vertical', // vertical or horizontal.
            barWidth: 10

        }                
            },
      axes:{
        xaxis:{                    
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
          min: '2011-10-15',
          max: '2011-11-13',
          tickInterval: "2 day",
          tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%d.%m'
          }          
        },
        yaxis:
        {
          min: 0,
          tickInterval: 1
        }        
      },
      highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
      },
      cursor: {
        show: false
      }
   });
```

But generated graph is wrong - first value is drawn OK - on 16.10.2011, but all other values (bars) are positioned incorrectly - one day sooner than they should be (even their "tooltip" when highlighted is OK, they are just in wrong place on x-axis). Any idea how to fix this?

See picture :
[image]

Comment: What browser reproduces the problem?  I tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/wN2SA/ (in firefox) and it works correctly.

Comment: really? screenshot is also from firefox, version 7

Comment: Mine was firefox 3.6, wow, might be time for an upgrade...

Comment: Just tried in firefox 8, same result as 3.6.  Pain in the arse that you can not link jqplot from jqplot.com, I had to cache each js file in my browser to get it to work with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in general, when dealing with barcharts you should always use ticks to have a nicer plot.
Also for your problem you obtain interesting results when using [this approach, please see here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/wN2SA/280/) Here you would need to remember that if you care on showing nothing for the days that are not specified in the `dataHits` you would need to provide them as well just giving them value of 0.

Interesting results you obtain (**hope this is what you want**) when you use both `ticks` and `dateAxisRenderer` capabilities. [This I show in the following sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/wN2SA/283/)  Here the gaps, showing time distance between the readings, are preserved and all values are correctly painted. Also important to notice the `min`, `max` and `tickInterval` have no effect since we use ticks.

**BTW:** If you still want to have some gaps around the chart you could apply [the approach presented in EDIT of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10447196/613495).

Comment: "A mere 4Y later" the links in the JS fiddle are broken

Comment: This happens when you build on top of assumptions that an URI will be available and as it happens the https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/ is not available anymore and the scripts were coming from there.
I updated those. Please have fun.

Comment: @OwenBeresford if you come across anything else not updated please do let me know.