# jqPlot - Set padding value to zero on date

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Problem is that it always is displaying two days before start of my chart. I've tried to set `pad: 0` and `min: 0` which is working on normal values, but not so much on date values.

Example:

My array starts at `2012.09.01` but chart starts at `2012.8.30`.

### Image describing problem

[image]

### Code

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart-dashboard', [line1, line2, line3], {
        series: [{ color: '#333333', label: '1' }, { color: '#999999', label: '2' }, { color: 'green', label: '3'}],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%b&nbsp;%#d'
                },
                // pad: 0 // does not work
                // min: 0 // does not work
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0 // works because it's not a date
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5
        },
        cursor: {
            show: false
        },
        legend: {
            show: true
        }
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem of yours ?

Answer (score 0):

In detail the way to resolve you problem described here

[Padding values on inverted axis in jqplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430972/padding-values-on-inverted-axis-in-jqplot/10447196#10447196)

In summary you should use

either

```
xaxis: {
     pad:0,
     ....
}
```

either

```
xaxis: {
     min:'2012.09.01',
     max: ....
}
```

because **pad** would not work if you set **max**, **min**