# Bar chart with jqplot and very large dataset

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am trying to use jqplot to print charts with hundreds of values, with dates as x-axis values.

I have no problem if I use a linear chart, the x labels are well distributed and spaced:
[image]

But when I try the same with a bar chart, the result is a mess:

[image]

I guess, and I have been searching for an example, if there is a way to distribute the dates labels in a barchart the same way you can make it with a linear chart.

Some information: for the barchar I use "renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer," and for the linear chart I use "renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer".

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqPlot date axis - bars drawn on wrong day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126484/jqplot-date-axis-bars-drawn-on-wrong-day)

Comment: No, the dates are correct. Every value has his label correctly assigned. If you watch them carefully, they have 5 minutes difference with each other, what is right.